# git diff-tree shows a delete but there's no delete in git log

Tags: git

`git diff-tree` indicates a file was deleted but when I run `git log`, it doesn't show anything.

To wit:

```
> git diff-tree --stat --summary 1990ca669fe..00de228dcdc -- t/tests.conf
t/tests.conf |    9 ---------
1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)
delete mode 100644 t/tests.conf
```

And when I run:

```
> git log 1990ca669fe..00de228dcdc -- t/tests.conf
```

I get no output.

Any idea I on how I can track down why git thinks this file has been deleted since it's also causing problems in a merge I'm trying?

**Update**

This doesn't produce any output either:

```
> git log 1990ca669fe...00de228dcdc -- t/tests.conf
```

And the commits are reachable:

```
 > git rev-list 00de228dcdc | grep 1990ca669fe
  1990ca669fe9ec94d215945388458daba8d94747
```

Comment: This was a tough nut to crack. I'm boggled as well. Waiting for VonC to clear things up :D

Comment: ha..glad I'm not alone. it's kind of driving me nuts.

Comment: @Magnus @Tyrone I suspect because of the meaning of '..' which might be different between diff-tree and log: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539040/not-able-to-think-of-a-case-where-git-diff-master-lab-and-git-diff-master-lab or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850607/difference-in-git-log-origin-master-vs-git-log-origin-master

Comment: I was suspecting that as well, but couldn't crack it. Thanks.

Comment: Or for an answer with graphical representations of the difference between '..' in `git log` and `git diff`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256249/git-diff-doesnt-show-enough/5257065#5257065

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that 1990ca669fe and 00de228dcdc have divergent histories (neither is reachable from the other). You probably want this command (three dots, not two):

```
git log 1990ca669fe...00de228dcdc -- t/tests.conf
```

It will show the commits from each side of the history (instead of just the commits leading to 00de228dcdc).

In short:
To see the “stuff” from **both sides** (A and B), use `git diff A..B` and `git log A...B`.
To only get “stuff” from **the second side** (B), use `git diff A...B` and `git log A..B`.

That is quite an unfortunate UI wart.

---

The “log” commands are about reviewing the history graph (commit “ranges”, or sets of commits).
They interpret `A..B` as equivalent to `B --not A` (i.e. the set of commits that are reachable from B but not from A). `A...B` is equivalent to `A B --not $(git merge-base --all A B)` (i.e. the set of commits from both sides since they diverged; this is called the “symmetric difference of A and B”).

The “diff” commands are about comparing two particular trees or blobs (just the “endpoints”, (mostly) not about any history that might connect them). They interpret `A..B` as equivalent to `A B` (i.e. just another way to directly specify the endpoints for a diff operation). `A...B` is equivalent to
`$(git merge-base A B)..B` or `$(git merge-base A B) B` (this is history-aware, thus the “mostly” above).

From [*git-diff(1)*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

> "diff" is about comparing two *endpoints*, not ranges, and the range notations ("<commit>..<commit>" and "<commit>...<commit>") do not mean a range as defined in the "SPECIFYING RANGES" section in [gitrevisions(7)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

---

Let us consider `git log A..B` and `git diff A..B` for two different kinds of history.

If A and B are linearly related (illustrated below),

```
---1---2---A---3---4---B
```

then you will see similar output for both types of commands. `git log A..B` will show the commits 3, 4 and B. `git diff A..B` will show the difference between the trees referenced by commits A and B; this diff will be equivalent to accumulating the patches represented by commits 3, 4, and B.

The three-dot versions are uninteresting since the merge base of A and B is A itself. For “log” commands, `A...B` means `A B --not $(git merge-base --all A B)`, which ends up being
`A B --not A`, which means `B --not A`, which is the same as `A..B`. For “diff” commands, `A...B` means `$(git merge-base A B)..B`, which ends up being `A..B`.

However, if A and B have divergent histories (neither is reachable from the other; illustrated below),

```
---1---D---3---4---A
        \
         5---6---B
```

then the diff will include changes from both branches while the log will only show the commits made to one of the branches. `git log A..B` will show commits 5, 6, and A. `git diff A..B` will show the difference between the trees referenced by commits A and B; this diff will include the patches represented by commits 5, 6, and B as well as by 3, 4, and A.

The three-dot variants are interesting in this case. For “log” commands, `A...B` means
`A B --not $(git merge-base --all A B)`, which ends up meaning `A B --not D`, which eventually expands to the set 3, 4, A, 5, 6, B (i.e. the commits that are reachable from A or B but not both). For “diff” commands, `A...B` means `$(git merge-base A B)..B`, which ends up being `D..B` (i.e. all the changes made on “B’s side” since B diverged from A).

Comment: Crystal clear: `"diff" is about comparing two endpoints, not ranges, and the range notations ("<commit>..<commit>" and "<commit>...<commit>") do not mean a range` - splendid explanation Chris

Comment: Thanks. This is a great answer so I'm upvoting. Unfortunately the triple dot in git log doesn't produce any output either. There's something weird doing on in my repo. I think the culprit is a reverted merge but I can't see anything in the logs where t/tests.conf is actually deleted so I'm confused as to why git thinks this is deleted when I do a diff on those commits.