# Use git log to find differences between when originally branched and current

Tags: git

I haven't seen something exactly like this, because most of what is out there talks about showing differences between the current origin/develop and the current branch.

What I'm after is the difference from when I branched off of develop (a month ago, for example; develop has changed since then) and what the changes are in my feature branch.

So, let's say that I branch from develop, change several files, and now I'm wanting to compare the differences between when I originally created the branch and now.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: `git diff develop...feature-X`**

#### Background on branches

Branches don't carry creation information—a branch *name* is just a pointer to one specific commit, with the special feature that when you are "on" the branch (as in, `git status` says `on branch xyz`"), and make a new commit, the pointer automatically moves to point to the new commit.

In other words, the branch name *automatically* points to the tip of the branch.  This is *how* branches work, and in git, we define "a branch" as "every commit we can get to, by starting with the tip commit to which the branch-name points."

(Side note: remote-tracking branches are similar, except that you cannot check them out to get "on" them, so *you* cannot update the remote-tracking branch.  The idea behind a remote-tracking branch is that it keeps track of commits *someone else* made, in the *remote* repository, by—over there—getting on that branch and making commits.  Since we're only interested in finding commits below, you can use `origin/develop` anywhere we've used `develop`.)

That said, as long as you (a) haven't merged anything in from the time you first created the branch, or (b) really want to see what's happened *since* that point, what you want is to diff against the *merge base*.

#### Merge base

Let's draw a bit of the commit graph, to show what I mean.  Suppose you're on `feature-X` and you branched from `develop` some commits ago, and `develop` has moved forward since then as well:

```
... <- o <- * <- o <- o <- o     <-- develop
             \
              o <- o <- o <- o   <-- feature-X
```

The commit marked `*` is where the two branches join up: commit `*`, and every earlier commit, is on *both* branches, while the commits "after" the one marked `*` are only on either `develop` or `feature-X`.  This point where the histories join is the *merge base*: the commit closest to the tip of the two branches that is on *both* branches.

It sounds like what you want at this point is to compare the contents of commit `*` against the contents of the tip-most commit on `feature-X`.

There are multiple ways to work with the merge base.  The most direct is to use `git merge-base`:

```
$ git merge-base feature-X develop
```

This prints the SHA-1 hash for the merge base, and you can now run:

```
$ git diff <sha-1> feature-X
```

to compare the given  to the commit to which `feature-X` points (which is, of course, the tip of that branch).

#### Three-dot syntax

It turns out, though, that the merge base is pretty useful in other ways.  Hence there's a special syntax in [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for working with two branch tips (or any two commits, really) and their merge base, namely the three-dot `X...Y` syntax.

Normally, `develop...feature-X` (note the three dots) means "every commit that is on *one* of these branches—either one—but no commit that is on *both* branches".  That is, it includes all the little `o` nodes *after* the merge base we drew as commit `*`, but not commit `*` itself, nor any of the commits before it.

With `git diff`, however, the three-dot syntax has a slightly different meaning:

```
$ git diff develop...feature-X
```

This finds the merge base between the two branches—i.e., commit `*`—and then diffs that merge base against the named right-hand-side commit, i.e., the tip of feature-X.

If you want to see what's happened in `develop`, simply reverse the two sides:

```
$ git diff feature-X...develop
```

As before, git will find the merge base, and then compare it to the right hand side commit, which this time is the tip of `develop`.

If you forget these details, look at the documentation for `gitrevisions` and `git diff`.

Comment: The thing that makes this the most understandable is the * asterisk. It was so much easier to get where you were talking about, using this different symbol. The discussion is great, too!

Comment: Good answer. Votes up :-)

Comment: On the three dots syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5257065/6309 +1. Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2539198/6309, and the old http://stackoverflow.com/a/53573/6309.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps here (though it is probably possible to come up with a one-liner if you care to):

1) [Find the last commit before the branch was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git)

2) Take the hash from (1) - let's call it `aabbcc` - and use it in diff: `git diff aabbcc..HEAD`